# Preserve Key Order: Loading JSON data into Snowflake VARIANT column using Python script

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was trying to extract the JSON response data from an API and load it into Snowflake VARIANT column using Python Script.

While loading the data, I noticed that the keys are re-arranged in alphabetical order.

Python/Postman data:

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "CompanyID": 3522,
      "MarketID": 23259,
      "MarketName": "XYZ_Market"
      "LocationID": 17745,
      "LocationName": "XYZ_Location"
    }
}
```

Snowflake data:

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "CompanyID": 3522,
      "LocationID": 17745,
      "LocationName": "XYZ_Location",
      "MarketID": 23259,
      "MarketName": "XYZ_Market"
    }
}
```

I was using PARSE_JSON() query function to load the data into snowflake. Is there any way to preserve the order of keys ?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Please also provide your Python code and snowflake schema

Comment: JSON is an un-ordered collection of name and value pair. You cannot guarantee order in JSON

Comment: What is the reason that the order of the keys is necessary?  Just curious, as I've seen this question before, but never understood it.  If you plan to query the data in Snowflake, the order of the keys will not matter.

Comment: its not python , it is parse_json function bringing key in order to increases the performance.

Comment: This was a question raised by one of our client and he wanted to know why exactly the JSON data in variant column in snowflake can't preserve the key order the same way Postman does. So it seems PARSE_JSON() snowflake function is changing the order for better performance. I know that we always have an option to flatten the data and represent the data/attributes in any order we would like to see using a curated view but I would like to know other options that we have from experts.

Comment: The answer is that the JSON spec designates objects as unordered. Therefore, Snowflake is free to change the order if it wants to and is still fully compliant with the JSON spec. There is no configuration in snowflake that allows you to order via PARSE_JSON or TO_JSON. You have to order objects yourself if you want them ordered. As you say, there are other means to get the same _effect_ with ordering when loading the data.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.6+ dictionaries maintain their insertion order. However, as noted in the [snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json.html#usage-notes) JSON objects are  ***unordered***. So, you may be limited by how your data is stored.

If you need to maintain order, consider an array of arrays, instead.

```py
    [
      ["CompanyID", 3522],
      ["MarketID", 23259],
      ["MarketName", "XYZ_Market"],
      ["LocationID", 17745],
      ["LocationName", "XYZ_Location"]
    ]
```

Comment: Actually I need to flatten the JSON data stored in VARIANT column using a view and array of arrays won't help me much.